# split index column based on existence of a substring

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
                              stuff
 james__America by Estonia :   2
 luke__Spain by Italy          3
 michael                       4
 Louis__Portugal by USA        2
```

I would like that in case in the index the substring "__" exists then I would like to split the index and create 2 new columns next to it to make a second split by ' by ' in order to get the following output:

```
            name1     name2    stuff
 james   America    Estonia      2
 luke    Spain       Italy       3
 michael   0           0         4
 Louis   Portugal     USA        2
```

I thought using :

```
 df.index.str.split('__', expand=True).split(' by ',expand=True).rename(columns={0:'name1',1:'name2'})
```

However it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Index` to `Series` by [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html), then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by first separator, then split by second column, join original columns and last overwrite index:

```
df1 = df.index.to_series().str.split('__', expand=True)

df2 = df1[1].str.split(' by ',expand=True).rename(columns={0:'name1',1:'name2'}).fillna('0')

df = df2.join(df)
df.index = df1[0].rename(None)
print (df)

            name1    name2  stuff
james     America  Estonia      2
luke        Spain    Italy      3
michael         0        0      4
Louis    Portugal      USA      2
```

Comment: df.index.to_frame()[0].

Comment: @ge00rge - Solution was changed